# Web config transformation condition/match to select a node based on parent node attribute

Tags: xpath, web-config-transform

I have a transform that looks like this

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <d>
          <e name="UpdateLanguageProfile">
            <f xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Condition(/..@name='UpdateLanguageProfile')">
              stuff here
            </f>
          </e>
        </d>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
```

So I want the xdt:Locator to select the f node only if the parent node has an attribute with the specified value.

The xdt:Locator gets translated into the following xpath expression:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f[/..@name='UpdateLanguageProfile']
```

Which is invalid.

So the question is, what could I put in the Condition, that is the XPath square brackets, in order to select the f node based on an attribute in the parent node.

Comment: What happens if you remove the xdt:Locator entirely? For me the transform works correctly as long as the parent has name attribute specified, as you have here...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is that the xdt:Locator and the xdt:Transform do not need to be on the same node.  They just happen to be on the same node in every example I've ever seen.

You can do this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <d>
          <e name="UpdateLanguageProfile" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <f xdt:Transform="Replace">
              stuff here
            </f>
          </e>
        </d>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
```

Comment: Great! I always worked with them on the same node, but this way solve some problems I had.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was trying to do inserts, but it kept adding to the first parent, not the current parent of the insert. This